# TypeScript Error for multiple types [Observables]

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have the following resolver class

```
export class UserResolverService implements Resolve<Observable<IUserAccount[] | IUserMoreInfo>>{

constructor(
  private userService: UserService,
  private router: Router
){}

resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<IUserAccount[] | IUserMoreInfo> {
.......
.........
        return this.userService.getUserAccounts(.....).pipe(
            take(1),
            map((res) => {
                console.log('Data', res);
                const data = res.data;
                const moreInfo = res.moreInfo;
                return {data, moreInfo};
            })
.......
........

}

}
```

For the above TS complains with following error, but when I return back the data with `res.data` the error disappears.

**Type '{ data: IUserAccount[]; moreInfo: IUserMoreInfo | undefined; }' is missing the following properties from type 'IUserAccount[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.ts(2322)**

The function that makes the request

```
public getUserAccounts = (....): Observable<IUserAccounts> => {
    return this.http.get<IUserAccounts>(`${url}`);
};
```

My interface definitions are as following

```
export interface IUserAccounts {
    data: IUserAccount[];
    moreInfo?: IUserMoreInfo;
}

export interface IUserAccount{
   name: string
   ......
   .....
}

export interface IUserMoreInfo{
   alias: string
   .....
   ......
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function declaration says that you are expecting it to return an observable stream of either `IUserAccount[]` or `IUserMoreInfo` and you are returning an observable stream of a custom object with both types in it,

```
{ data: IUserAccount[]; moreInfo: IUserMoreInfo | undefined; }
```

So your return type does not match the function declaration. You either need to change your return type to be `moreInfo` OR `data` (not both), or you need to update your function signature.

Comment: what about the case where i need to return both

Comment: Then you would need to change your function signature to return this, Observable<IUserAccount[] | IUserMoreInfo | {data: IUserAccount[]; moreInfo: IUserMoreInfo | undefined;}>